# Does it exist any SQLite lock can prevent to query a record?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have an upsert method in my Android app. It query a record by id, and if it does not exist `INSERT` anyway `UPDATE` is performed.

DB can be modified quite frequently. I do not know much about SQLite locking mechanism.

Is it possible that some lock is retained on a record and so query will not return it?

---

If exception occurs on an INSERT operation like:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: column _id is not unique (code 19)
```

Can I perform an `UPDATE` in catch clause?

---

I tryed  `REPLACE INTO`, but it has no effect. Not crashes, but has no effect:

```
String queryString = "REPLACE INTO " + recordType + " (" + keys + ") VALUES (" + values + ")";
statement.executeUpdateDelete(); // <-- tried all 3 option: execute, executeInsert, executeUpdateDelete
```

[image]

Comment: Use `REPLACE INTO`, instead of `INSERT INTO`. This is what i call an "upsert". It tries to insert. Then, if it fails, it updates.

Comment: @Rotwang tried  `REPLACE INTO`, something wrong, it has no effect ..

Comment: Did you try executing the command with [`execSQL()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL(java.lang.String))?

Comment: @Rotwang Thanks, works now. :)

Comment: Glad that it helped. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can either use [`insertWithConflict()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insertWithOnConflict(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20int)) and specify `SqliteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE`, or you can wrap your logic in a transaction:

```
db.beginTransaction();
try {
    // query for record
    // if found, update; otherwise, insert
    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
} finally {
    db.endTransaction();
}
```